# MethodNowAllowedHTTPException in Laravel 5.4 on delete action

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am working on a Laravel 5.4 application in which I want to enable the user to delete certain images which they have uploaded. The images have a small `x` on the right top which makes a modal pop up. I added a partial code of the modal form. When I want to submit the destroy option I get the error:

**(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)**

Could someone help me explain what I am doing wrong. I have tried changing the method in the form to `DELETE` and changed the route file to `get`, `post`, `any` etc.

> Modal popup:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#destroyModel" data-route="{{ route('client.progress.destroy', [$progressPicture]) }}" data-name="{{ $progressPicture->original_file }}" data-value="{{ $progressPicture->id }}">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
</a>
```

> Modal form:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="ud9UPrV3tXJ0iuQ96TELClQUcTksKx3Bimv54h9Z">
      <input name="id" type="hidden" value="">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i> Verwijderen</button>
</form>
```

> Route file

```
Route::post('destroy_progress', 'Client\PictureController@destroyProgress')->name('progress.destroy');
```

> JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#destroyModel').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            let button = $(event.relatedTarget);// Button that triggered the modal
            let modal = $(this);

            let original_file = button.data('original_file');

            let title = ":original_file verwijderen?";
            title = title.replace(":original_file", original_file);
            let message = "Weet u heel zeker dat u :original_file wilt verwijderen?";
            message = message.replace(":original_file", name);

            modal.find('.modal-footer form').attr('action', button.data('route'));
            modal.find('.modal-title').html(title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(message);
            modal.find('.modal-footer input[name=id]').val(button.data('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm trying to comment.
You should use `get()` method instead of `post()` for delete.

Comment: why action is action="#"   ?

Comment: @JYoThI data route is already given

Comment: Your method such as `get` `post` etc should match with action in the controller function. In case of missmatch such exception has been thrown. please check it.

Comment: I have changed the method to get and post but with no luck. I believe it has to be delete also due to the request: `request_request
array:3 [ "_method" => "delete"`

Comment: Can you add your controller function `destroyProgress` ?

Comment: FOUND THE ISSUE: The JS is suppose to give the action attribute from the `<a.....` to the modal, but this fails. I manually changed the `action=#` to a legit action path and changed the method to `get` which succeeded!

Comment: Congrats you found solution your self :D

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

To generate the hidden input field _method, you may also use the method_field helper function:

```
<?php echo method_field('PUT'); ?>
```

You can also do it using laravel blade template as

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Then create a route which accepts the `PUT` request as

```
Route::put('destroy_progress', 'Client\PictureController@destroyProgress')->name('progress.destroy');
```

Comment: Thank you for this but unfortunately I still am getting the same error. :-(

Comment: FOUND THE ISSUE: The JS is suppose to give the action attribute from the `<a.....` to the modal, but this fails. I manually changed the `action=#` to a legit action path and changed the method to `get` which succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest using Laravel Forms
here is the link https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html but instead of using `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"` just use this `composer require "laravelcollective/html"` to get the latest version, because the latest version solved the syntactical errors, the most common was the `token()` method